# How does Java link lib/rt.jar to your app at runtime?

Tags: java, linker, jvm, classloader

The Java standard/system libraries (`java.*`, `javax.*`, etc.) are stored in `lib/rt.jar` inside each JRE distribution.

Say I have an application that I have compiled and `jar`red into `myapp.jar`. This JAR only contains my app's class files, and merely *references* system classes like `System`, `File`, `Runtime`, `Thread`, `String`, `Boolean`, etc.

So when I run my app, say via `java -jar myapp.jar`, the JVM is obviously doing so last minute linking (or something) where it is executing the bytecode of my class files (inside `myapp.jar`) and then "jumping" into `lib/rt.jar` to run bytecode located there. I would imagine the process is the same if `myapp.jar` depends on other JARs provided on the runtime `classpath`.

My question is: what is this "linking" process called, and how does it essentially work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That `rt.jar` is part of the bootstrap classpath, a parent of the usual classpath you already know and that you configure when you use the `-cp` option (you can actually change the bootstrap classpath too using the `-Xbootclasspath` option to load, for example, a custom Java runtime).

See Oracle documentation for a [detailed description](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/findingclasses.html) of how classes are searched/loaded from the system defined classpaths hierarchy.

Now, the additional questions you seemed to have:

1. How is the archive actually *found*?

   It's simply hardcoded. If the `java` binary is located in `<common_root>/bin/java`, rt.jar will be searched in `<common_root>/lib/rt.jar`.
2. How is the "linking" performed?

   On the JVM there is no actual linking, the classes are dynamically loaded using a mechanism based on a hierarchy of ClassLoader that are the software components that actually do the class file loading/parsing. When you try to load a class, the search starts from the application-facing default classloader(or a child classloader if you have defined one) and if the class cannot be loaded the loading attempt is repeated with a parent classloader until the bootstrap classloader is reached.

   If the class is found, the `.class` file is loaded, parsed and internal structures representing the class and its data are created.Once the class is loaded a new instance can be created.
   If instead, even the boot classloader could not load your class a user-visible `ClassNotFoundException` is thrown.